# Android Retrofit - parse objects as list

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit to get data from thing speak. And response that I am getting is containing JSON objects like "field1", "field2" etc. Is it possible to parse this data by Retrofit to get list containing of this elements?

For now I have parsing made like this:

```
@SerializedName("field1")
val field1: Float?,
@SerializedName("field2")
val field2: Float?,
@SerializedName("field3")
val field3: Float?,
@SerializedName("field4")
val field4: Float?,
@SerializedName("field5")
val field5: Float?,
@SerializedName("field6")
val field6: Float?,
@SerializedName("field7")
val field7: Float?,
@SerializedName("field8")
val field8: Float?
```

Response that I am getting:

```
{"created_at":"2019-05-24T06:11:43Z","entry_id":15419693,"field1":"370","field2":"56.390658174097666"}
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
@SerializedName("field[]")
val fields List<Float>
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: No! `@SerializedName("field[]")` means dynamic keys are there in in your `Web Api response` that's can not be handle by `Retrofit`. Keys must be static values may be dynamics.

Comment: @NickBapu - so the only thing I can do is use separate field for each value? Like @SerializedName("field1"), @SerializedName("field2") etc.?

Comment: Yes. And I never seen this before `JSON object's` keys are dynamic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom JSON parser, but it isn't recommended. It's much better to use Retrofit parser.

You can't parse as you described, but it would be much better if you could update server response, so it looks like this:

```
{"created_at":"2019-05-24T06:11:43Z","entry_id":15419693,"fields":["370",:"56.390658174097666", "45"]}
```

And then in your class define

```
 @SerializedName("fields")
 var fields: List<Float>?
```

**EDIT:**

If you can't update server response, everything you can do is to define helper function:

```
 public fun getFields() : ArrayList<Float?> {
        var list = ArrayList<Float?>()

        list.add(field1)
        list.add(field2)
        list.add(field3)
        list.add(field4)
        list.add(field5)
        list.add(field6)
        list.add(field7)
        list.add(field8)

        list.removeIf { it == null }

        return list;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately response is from thingspeak.com, and I cannot change it.

Comment: I've edited answer, it's just helpful, it doesn't resolve your problem :)
It should be fixed on server side.